# Clojure: leiningen - making sure all the plugins get installed

Tags: plugins, clojure, leiningen

This is my ~/.lein/profiles.clj:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-idefiles "0.2.1"]]}}
{:user {:plugins [[lein-droid "0.3.0-beta4"]]}}
{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.1"]]}}
```

I've got an impression that the cider-nrepl plugin is not installed. Nothing in ~/.m2/repository, etc. Is there a regular way to check the status of all plugins short of trial and error with real projects?

Answer (score 0):

Your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` seems invalid. It should be something like:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-idefiles "0.2.1"]
                  [lein-droid "0.3.0-beta4"]
                  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.1"]]}}
```

Comment: This is prettier indeed, but the verbose version is hardly invalid.

Comment: All examples of `profiles.clj` I ever saw held a single hashmap with one or several profiles. I never saw any evidence in [`profiles.clj` docs](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md), or in any other source of information, that your version works. But I never saw any proof that it is invalid, either.

Comment: You are probably right, but that's trial and error again, which I'd like to dispense with. Leiningen is a package manager, among other things, and package managers are usually helpful about the installed packages info.